# WSO2 APIM: Unable to generate REST APIs from SOAP Backends

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API Manager version: 2.6.0

This link suggests that it is possible to generate REST APIs from a SOAP Endpoint:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Generate+REST+APIs+from+SOAP+Backends

but when i choose **Generate REST APIs** option, WSO2 APIM is not generating the operations under **API Definitions** in *Design API* section as explained in the wso2 documentation, 
instead this API section shows WSDL URL with **Test URI** button

I could see an INFO log when i click "Start Creating" button which says

**INFO - SOAPOperationBindingUtils No SOAP operations found in the WSDL**

Kindly advise on how to generate REST APIs using SOAP wsdl

[Design API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7k7t.png)

[Manage section screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om5Wk.png)

[Generate REST APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qidCg.png)

below is the WSDL used to generate REST APIs

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://www.r2services.com" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.r2services.com" name="CompanyService">
   <types>
      <xsd:schema>
         <xsd:import namespace="http://www.r2services.com" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/r2ws/updateCompany?xsd=1" />
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="updateCompany">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateCompany" />
   </message>
   <message name="updateCompanyResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateCompanyResponse" />
   </message>
   <message name="R2Exception">
      <part name="fault" element="tns:R2Exception" />
   </message>
   <message name="Exception">
      <part name="fault" element="tns:Exception" />
   </message>
   <portType name="CompanyService">
      <operation name="updateCompany">
         <input wsam:Action="http://www.r2services.com/updateCompany" message="tns:updateCompany" />
         <output wsam:Action="http://www.r2services.com/CompanyService/updateCompanyResponse" message="tns:updateCompanyResponse" />`enter code here`
         <fault message="tns:R2Exception" name="R2Exception" wsam:Action="http://www.r2services.com/CompanyService/updateCompany/Fault/R2Exception" />
         <fault message="tns:Exception" name="Exception" wsam:Action="http://www.r2services.com/CompanyService/updateCompany/Fault/Exception" />
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="UpdateCompanyServicePortBinding" type="tns:CompanyService">
      <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
      <operation name="updateCompany">
         <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.r2services.com/updateCompany" />
         <input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
         </output>
         <fault name="R2Exception">
            <soap12:fault name="R2Exception" use="literal" />
         </fault>
         <fault name="Exception">
            <soap12:fault name="Exception" use="literal" />
         </fault>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="CompanyService">
      <port name="UpdateCompanyServicePort" binding="tns:UpdateCompanyServicePortBinding">
         <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/r2ws/updateCompany" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

i am also observing below *error* on click of **Start Creating** button

[2019-12-30 11:57:50,011]  INFO - SOAPOperationBindingUtils No SOAP operations found in the WSDL
[2019-12-30 11:57:50,115] ERROR - add:jag org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag#227)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_5(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:227)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:54)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: still awaiting to hear suggestion/help on this issue.. Kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you selected the `Pass Through` option. Make sure you have selected the `Generate REST APIs` option instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bee, but i am selecting *Generate REST APIs* option. i have updated my original post by attaching this screenshot and also more error log.. Kindly advise